# Mapping main domain and subdomain to different nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver

I have mapped my main domain to a different hosting using NS record.

but I want to map a subdomain on the same hosting. What DNS setting do I need to configure?

Example:

`abc.com` is mapped to `ns1.xyz.com` and `ns2.xyz.com`

but I want `subdomain.abc.com` to be mapped to same hosting i.e. `ns1.abc.com` and `ns2.abc.com`

how do I achieve this scenario?

Comment: the duplicate article is about server I think. I am configuring it on a shared hosting.

Comment: You need to read and **understand** that article much more carefully.  It shows you how to delegate a subdomain by putting `NS` records into the parent zone, which is what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate spells it out indeed, but I wonder if in your case you could just add an A record to the existing DNS and point it to the target IP address instead (no need to first point to NameServers).

subdomain.abc.com. A 123.456.789.100

If there's a webserver on that IP address listening on port 80 and expecting that alias/hostname, that's the easiest route.

Comment: [The target of a CNAME cannot be an IP address.](http://serverfault.com/a/377956)

Comment: Of course you are right, sorry and thanks for correcting. I meant an A record.